# Image uploaded on firebase by iOS camera get rotated 90 degree left on Android and web

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage, image-rotation

I am working on app that needs image to uploaded on firebase storage and URL of that image is stored on firebase database. Problem is whenever i upload the image to storage using camera image, Image gets rotated by -90 degree in android and web version of app.
Strange thing is image is correct whenever i get image from imageURL generated by firebase storage. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
      let imageName = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
      dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
      })
   }

   func uploadImageOnStorage() { 
         // uploading image to firebase storage
          let metaData = StorageMetadata()
          metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
          let storageRef = storage.reference().child("Photos/\(self.timeStampString)")

          if let uploadImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.1){
                    storageRef.putData(uploadImage, metadata: metaData, completion: {(metadata, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            // show alert
                        }
                        if let imageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                        //upload imageUrl on firebase database
                        }
          }
   }
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with EXIF data, I know that image tags in web does not account for exif data, so you have to do that yourself. I don't know how android works. AFAIK Swift will handle the data for you, and display the image correctly. This is why the image appears differently on these platforms. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be that you're compression the image so much when using UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.1). You can also rotate the image before you upload it, which is a quick and dirty fix.

```
let imageToUpload: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: self.imageView .image.cgImage, scale: self.imageView.image.scale, orientation: .right)
```